# Scheduled Jobs and Custom Clock Processes with Clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, clockwork

I am trying to understand how to execute custom code with clockwork. This is the example `lib/clock.rb` file that Heroku uses in its devcenter document.

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'

include Clockwork

every(4.minutes, 'Queueing interval job') { Delayed::Job.enqueue IntervalJob.new }
every(1.day, 'Queueing scheduled job', :at => '14:17') { Delayed::Job.enqueue ScheduledJob.new }
```

What is IntervalJob and ScheduledJob? Where are these files supposed to be located? I want to run my own custom job that has access to my database records.

**EDIT**

This is my `/lib/clock.rb`

```
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork

  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every(2.minutes, 'Filtering Streams') { Delayed::Job.enqueue FilterJob.new}
end
```

This is my `/lib/filter_job.rb`

```
  class FilterJob
    def perform
      @streams = Stream.all

      @streams.each do |stream|
      # manipulating stream properties
      end
    end
   end
```

I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Clockwork::FilterJob (NameError)
/app/lib/clock.rb:11:in `block in <module:Clockwork>'
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following:

Firstly install the clockwork gem.

In your lib folder create a clock.rb

```
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork

  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every(1.day, 'Creating Cycle', :at => '22:00') { Delayed::Job.enqueue CyclePlannerJob.new}
end
```

In the example your provided IntervalJob and ScheduledJob, are delayed jobs. Clockwork triggers them on the time specified. I am calling the CyclePlannerJob, this is what my file looks like. 
lib/cycle_planner_job.rb

```
class CyclePlannerJob
  def perform
    CyclePlanner.all.each do |planner|
      if Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").to_date.send("#{planner.start_day.downcase}?")
        planner.create_cycle
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my example everyday at 10pm, I am running the CyclePlanner job, which runs the delayed job I have setup. Similar to the Heroku example. 
Bare in mind to use this you need to setup the clock work and delayed jobs on your Heroku app in the dashboard. 
Also your Procfile should look like this.

```
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I can go into more detail if needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, I got an error when I tried running it on Heroku, I updated my question. I have the procfile set up exactly like yours

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: What happens when run "clockwork lib/clock.rb" from the terminal

Comment: Open your console 'rails c' and try running 'Delayed::Job.enqueue FilterJob.new' To ensure that the delayed job is setup properly. You have the gem installed right?

Comment: Yes I have the gem installed, I still get NameError: uninitialized constant FilterJob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57606/discussion-between-shivamd-and-user3646037).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like name space issue. Move your filter_job.rb to models directory and try.